# reactjs Delete Operation Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `role` is marked as required in `ManageRolePage`, but its value is `null`

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I am working on a reactjs project and I am adding in delete functionality into my app. I have created a delete button on the form component and on the parent component in the manage-role-page I pass in a PropType of role. I have a `onDelete` property I pass into the child component the delete method and to be honest most of this functionality works.

manage-role.js

```
deleteRole(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({deleting: true});
    this.props.actions.deleteRole(this.state.role)
      .then(() => this.redirectDelete())
      .catch(error => {
        toastr.error(error);
        this.setState({deleting: false});
      });
  }
```

Render Function:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/roles" />;
    }

return (
   <RoleForm
     errors={this.state.errors}
     onChange={this.updateRoleState}
     onSave={this.saveRole}
     onDelete={this.deleteRole}
     role={this.state.role}
     saving={this.state.saving}
     deleting={this.state.deleting}
   />
 );
}
```

Props config on this component

```
ManageRolePage.propTypes = {
  role: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Here is the child component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextInput from '../common/text-input';

const RoleForm = ({role, onSave, onChange, onDelete, saving, deleting, errors}) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Manage Role</h1>
      <div>{role._id}</div>
      <TextInput
        name="role"
        label="Role"
        value={role.role}
        onChange={onChange}
        error={errors.role}/>

      <TextInput
        name="notes"
        label="Notes"
        value={role.notes}
        onChange={onChange}
        error={errors.notes}/>

      <div>{role.createdDate}</div>
      <div>{role.dateModified}</div>

      <input
        type="submit"
        disabled={saving}
        value={saving ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={onSave} />

      <input
        type="submit"
        disabled={deleting}
        value={deleting ? 'Deleting...' : 'Delete'}
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={onDelete}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

RoleForm.propTypes = {
  role: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDelete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  saving: PropTypes.bool,
  deleting: PropTypes.bool,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
};

export default RoleForm;
```

Reducer looks like this:

```
import * as types from '../actions/action-types';
import initialState from './initial-state';

export default function roleReducer(state = initialState.roles, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_ROLES_SUCCESS:
      return action.roles;

    case types.CREATE_ROLE_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.role)
        ];

    case types.UPDATE_ROLE_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state.filter(role => role._id !== action.role._id),
        Object.assign({}, action.role)
      ];

    case types.DELETE_ROLE_SUCCESS: {
      let newState = Object.assign([], state);
      const indexOfRoleToDelete = state.findIndex(role => {
        return role._id === action.role._id;
      });

      newState.splice(indexOfRoleToDelete, 1);
      return newState;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

When I click delete the call is made to the API but then I want the code to redirect to the role list component. I have this working but I get an warning because it goes back to the manage-form-page that has the child form component and the form has the following prop config:

```
RoleForm.propTypes = {
  role: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDelete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  saving: PropTypes.bool,
  deleting: PropTypes.bool,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Warning I get is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `role` is marked as required in 
`ManageRolePage`, but its value is `null`.
    in ManageRolePage (created by Connect(ManageRolePage))
    in Connect(ManageRolePage) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider
```

And the page does redirect because the form manages the delete redirect like so in the manage-role-page.js.

```
 deleteRole(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({deleting: true});
    this.props.actions.deleteRole(this.state.role)
      .then(() => this.redirectDelete())
      .catch(error => {
        toastr.error(error);
        this.setState({deleting: false});
      });
  }

  redirectSave() {
    this.setState({saving: false, deleting: false, redirect: true});
    toastr.success('Role saved');
  }

  redirectDelete() {
    this.setState({saving: false, deleting: false, redirect: true});
    toastr.success('Role deleted');
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/roles" />;
    }

    return (
      <RoleForm
        errors={this.state.errors}
        onChange={this.updateRoleState}
        onSave={this.saveRole}
        onDelete={this.deleteRole}
        role={this.state.role}
        saving={this.state.saving}
        deleting={this.state.deleting}
      />
    );
  }
```

If I remove the following prop setting in the manage-role-page.js

```
ManageRolePage.propTypes = {
  role: PropTypes.object,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

`Notice now the role is not set to required, I get no warning`.

So my question is should I be doing the redirect back to the role list in the reducer and if so what is the best practice way of doing this, but to me I have read this is not best way, so currently I have coded it to manage this in the manage-role-page.js. And if I manage this here I break the rule for the Prop of `role: PropTypes.object.isRequired,`. So should I not be setting this property as required, as when we trigger the delete and the reducer completes it task and pass back to the manage-role-page.js so that it handles the redirect back to the role-list.js as the page now has a scenario of loading without a role property being set as this will be null on a delete operation. I am just trying to understand the best way of managing this scenario. I am sure this is something that a lot of developer would have come across.

Do I manage the redirect in the reducer, or back to the ManageRole component and not have the required property set for the role on the manage-role-page.js? Any example on how to manage this differently, or the best way to manage this would be great too see.

package.json dependency to show versions are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.8",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "toastr": "2.1.4"
  },
```

You responses are appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where you are setting the data to the role state property and what is it’s initial value? You need to check something like {this.state.role != null && <RoleForm
     errors={this.state.errors}
     onChange={this.updateRoleState}
     onSave={this.saveRole}
     onDelete={this.deleteRole}
     role={this.state.role}
     saving={this.state.saving}
     deleting={this.state.deleting}
   />}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that warning(looks like it’s a warning) but impacts your functionality because the role value is null at the time of rendering. Probably what you have to do is, check the role and when it is not null then call RoleForm component

```
{this.state.role != null && typeof this.state.role != undefined && <RoleForm
 errors={this.state.errors}
 onChange={this.updateRoleState}
 onSave={this.saveRole}
 onDelete={this.deleteRole}
 role={this.state.role}
 saving={this.state.saving}
 deleting={this.state.deleting}
   />}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Good point should be checking the role before loading RoleForm. Should I be setting the PropType for role in the manage-role-page.js as required? As the delete removes the role and set it to null in the state? Is this the correct way to do the redirect in the component or to do it in the reducer?

Comment: Yeah good practice is to have prop types defined to understand better about the component on high level but not manadatory. we basically redirect from component. What you are doing is correct but it just that you are calling RoleForm always irrespective of the role is null or it has value.

Comment: Done the following:
```
    render() {
        if(this.state.redirect) {
          return <Redirect to="/roles" />;
        }

        if(this.state.role !== null && typeof this.state.role !== undefined) {
          return (
            <RoleForm
              errors={this.state.errors}
              onChange={this.updateRoleState}
              onSave={this.saveRole}
              onDelete={this.deleteRole}
              role={this.state.role}
              saving={this.state.saving}
              deleting={this.state.deleting}
            />
          );
        }
      }

Comment: And set `role: PropTypes.object,` in the manage-role-page.js
This has worked and removed the warning.

Comment: Perfect Glad I am able to help and I am constantly learning.

Comment: Yes, you confirmed things for me :) Thank you
I needed confirmation that my approach was using best practices. There are examples I have seen that show redirects done in the reducer and I was not sure if this was correct or the component should handle this. You have confirmed this to me and also pointed out that we should be checking the Props before calling RoleForm. Like a peer review. So thank you.